# NLA : is it possible to "hold backward" an action strip?

Tags: nla-editor, actions

I know about the *Hold Forward* extrapolation mode of an action strip in the NLA, which allows you to to extend the pose of the action strip.

But is there a way to "hold Backward" ?
I mean, I would like that my pose starts sooner but without changing the timing of my action.

Thanks !

Comment: Have you tried the "Hold" Extrapolation Mode? This allows you to hold the first frame and the last Frame of an action strip. This works in both ways. Or do you want it only "Backwards"?

Answer (score 1):

In case someone comes looking for this. When I need to implement "Hold Backwards only", I set extrapolation to "Hold" and add a non-zero blend-out. With a non-zero blend-out, hold forward is effectively negated.